Designing a Y-Junction for Dual ID Fans in a Chemical Incineration Plant
I’m a mechanical supervisor working in a chemical incineration plant, and I’ve been assigned a project by my manager (who doesn’t have an engineering background). Here’s the challenge I’m dealing with:
We have two plants—one with a vertical system and one with a rotary system. In the rotary system, an Induced Draft (ID) fan creates suction to pull flue gases from the rotary kiln and discharge them through the chimney. My manager asked me to redesign the duct system so we can connect two ID fans in either a Y-shaped or T-shaped duct configuration. The goal is to use one fan as a backup while the other is operating.
Constraints and Requirements:
The ducts are circular and handle high-temperature, slightly corrosive flue gases.
The solution must result in minimal pressure loss and maintain high efficiency for the operating fan.
We’re considering options like:

Diverter dampers (two-way, straight-leg, three-way).
Motorized butterfly dampers.

My Questions:

Which type of damper/diverter would work best for maintaining efficiency and minimizing pressure drop in this setup?

Has anyone worked on a similar system, and are there specific design considerations or lessons learned?

Are there better alternatives to the above solutions that I should consider?


I’ve been researching diverter dampers and butterfly dampers as they seem to have lower pressure losses, but I’m open to suggestions. I want to make sure I present solid options to my manager.
Any advice or product recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Have two short sections of pipe each with an ID fan in it and have them on a frame allowing one to be rotated into service while the other is cleaned.
